# Main menu displayed twice

Tags: templates, extensions, menu-item, menu

[My website](http://www.healthliteracyhub.com) is showing two blog menu items? Above menu and in the menu items!

I want to remove blog item which is showing above the menu?

Answer (score 2):

Your website is in offline-mode, so it's not possible to know what's going on.

However, the Helix3 template has a menu system that is [configured in the template](http://www.joomshaper.com/documentation/helix3/mega-menu-settings) settings, and my guess is that you have one or more menu modules *in addition* to the default menu loaded by the template framework.

Go to your module manager (**Extensions** - >**Modules**), and filter the modules by *Type* -> *Menu*:

[image: Menu filter]

Unpublish any module that could be displaying your main menu.

Comment: @AmiraliPanjwani no problem, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can always remove/unpublish any menu item from **Menu Manager > Menu Group(Main menu) > individual menu**.

You can try [ThemeXpert Joomla templates](https://www.themexpert.com/joomla-templates) that comes is a easy-to-use mega menu.

Thanks